# Problem with KeyPress Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I call a javascript function from a textbox by using OnKeyPress="clickSearchButton()"

Here is my function:

```
function clickSearchButton()
{
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var btnSearch = document.getElementById("TopSubBanner1_SearchSite1_btnSearchSite");
  if(code == 13);
      {          
           btnSearch.click(); 
           return false; 
      } 
}
```

My problem is that this function fires when the user hits the enter button in any textbox, not just the one that calls the function.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  Still not working correctly.  So I'll throw my HTML out there if that helps.

```
<input name="TopSubBanner1:SearchSite1:txtSearch" type="text" id="TopSubBanner1_SearchSite1_txtSearch" OnKeyPress="clickSearchButton(this)" /><input type="submit" name="TopSubBanner1:SearchSite1:btnSearchSite" value="Search" id="TopSubBanner1_SearchSite1_btnSearchSite" />
```

Also, this is an ASP.NET page if that makes a difference.

Comment: How are you connecting your clickSearchButton function to the OnKeyPress event?

Comment: You should change the title of this to not be so vague.  At least mention the keypress event.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing 'this' to your handler.

Comment: Thanks J-P.  Is there anything I should be passing in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is by default passed as an argument to your function, but your not capturing it as a parameter.  If you capture it, the above should work correctly.

```
function clickSearchButton(e)
{
   e = e || window.event //for IE compliane (thanks J-P)
   //etc
```

or

```
function clickSearchButton()
{
   var e = arguments[0];
   e = e || window.event;
```

Also you have an extra semicolon as Kevin pointed out.

Comment: Alternatively `arguments[0]`.

Comment: Also, you'll want it to work in IE. So e = e || window.event;

Answer (score 4):

```
function clickSearchButton(e)
{
  var code;

if(window.event)
    code = e.keyCode;
else
   code = e.which;

var btnSearch = document.getElementById("TopSubBanner1_SearchSite1_btnSearchSite");
  if(code == 13)
      {          
           btnSearch.click(); 
           return false; 
      } 
}
```

and your calling method should be:

```
onkeypress="clickSearchButton(event)"
```